# How to ? Espressif IOT Plateform

Tags: iot, esp8266, arduino-ide, freertos, arduino-esp8266

I am a non-software guy with some hands-on with Arduino IDE and ESP-12E. I want to use Arduino IDE and ESP-12E for testing Espressif IOT App. I have gone through almost all resources but could not find a step-by-step guide on:

1. How exactly to flash the FREE RTOS SDK to ESP-12E? What files in what bins? And what locations?
2. What is the Arduino code? I found some literature and code on [GitHub](https://github.com/wujiangang/ESP8266_IOT_PLATFORM)  but this is quite abstract for me as it assumes advanced user knowledge.

Can someone tell me how to go about step by step to test Espressif IOT App?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the ESP RTOS SDK is not yet supported by the Arduino platform. You will have to use another IDE that supports CMake (Eclipse, Visual Studio) and integrate the ESP SDK with the IDE. Keep in mind that development on the RTOS platform requires a good level of programming know-how.

You cannot "flash" the RTOS SDK onto an ESP chip: the SDK is a toolchain that is used to develop the binaries that you flash onto the chip. There are several quickstart guides on the Espressif website to get started with the SDK, but as you are not familiar with development using embedded toolchains, I suggest that you stick to Arduino platform for now.